# How do I make my footer stay at the bottom as Stackoverflow's?

Tags: html, css

I wonder how I make my footer stick to the bottom as Stackoverflow's.

If I give it a position:absolute and bottom:0px; it stays at the same place. Nor I want a position:fixed; one.

I've been searching the web for a while now but I can't find the right solution.
Thankful for every answear!

Comment: StackOverflow's footer does not do that.

Comment: [Sticky footer](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want the footer to do? Your example of StackOverflow isn't clear because StackOverflow's footer doesn't do anything special...

Comment: Ok, the sticky footer is just what I needed, thank you guys alot!

Comment: [http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for a sticky footer. You can find an example at [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will accept the answear in 8 min.

Comment: Currently this is a comment, not an answer. Answers are expected to contain enough information that they could stand alone. If you're going to include resources from a linked page, it's important to quote the relevant information so that the content is maintained if the link no longer works.

Comment: Oh thanks for mentioning that as I'm still a StackOverflow answer newbie. Will keep it in mind for the next question.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be to add the `clear: both` property to your CSS footer class.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the links below for working Examples:

[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/juroto/HL6Ad/)

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/biznuge/thbuf/8/)

[Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/cristian_cena/4awwx/)

```
   #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#CCC;
    color:#333;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this css to the footer class:

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
   <p>Copyright 2013</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
width: 100%;
position:relative;
bottom: 0; //fixes the footer to the bottom of the page.
height: 80px;
}
```